# Can I use the sealed TOEFL score report I receive from ETS as an official score report

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, computer-science, language-exams, toefl

ETS sends a score report to me after each TOEFL exam in a sealed envelope. And since I already have online access to my scores, I would like to know if I can use the sealed score report as an official score report, would it be considered official by universities? Or only test scores sent by ETS directly to the university are considered official.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some schools will accept a copy of your test score report as an **unofficial** report of test scores. However, if this is the case, this will usually be explicitly stated in the admissions documentation from the university. If they do not specify that this is allowed, then normally only the report submitted directly by ETS is acceptable.